# I want to delete all the values of particular column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SSMS and want to delete the values of a column without deleting the entire column which is the country as mentioned in ScreenShot.

[image: Hi I'm using SQL server management studio and wants to delete the values of a column without deleting the entire column which is the country column as mentioned in SS]

Comment: Firstly, you have to allow NULL values in your column, To do so  run ALTER TABLE your_table_name modify column your_column_name data_type

Then, update the values to null by running UPDATE your_table_name set your_column_name = NULL;

Comment: In SSMS, I think you just need to select the entire column and set it to empty.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
UPDATE [JoinClauses].[dbo].[Customers]
SET [Country] = NULL;
```

Comment: If Country does not allow NULL, `UPDATE [JoinClauses].[dbo].[Customers]
SET [Country] = ''` --Setting to Emptystring